# Creating responsive box based on size of window

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following code with the intent of creating box area whose size is related to screen size of access device as in mobile vs pc, etc.

```
import React, { useRef, useState} from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const TweetSheet = ({classes}) => {
    const winWidth = useState(window.innerWidth)
    const winHeight = useState(window.innerHeight)    

    return (
        <div className={classes.ts1}>
          TextArea
        </div>
    );
  }

  const styles = (winWidth, winHeight) => (
    {      
      ts1: {
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          border: "3px solid",
          borderRadius: "5px",
          // width: "600px",
          width: (winWidth * 0.05),
          // minHeight: "200px",
          minHeight: (winHeight *0.01),
          padding: "20px"
      },           
    })

  export default withStyles(styles)(TweetSheet)
```

But even though I am using the window size for definition of height and width, the box is not responsive.

Comment: Use `vh` and `vw` units instead of trying to calculate in javascript. `5vh` is equal to `winWidth * 0.05`. https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Comment: It might be because the div has `display: "flex"` which causes it to ignore the width and height since it changes dimensions on window resize.